# CkFinder Java ResourceType in Access Control not work

Tags: java, ckfinder

I have a problem with ckfinder in java, the resourceType in accessControl not works. This is my ckfinder.yml :

```
enabled: true # Change this value to "true" to enable the application

licenseName: ~
licenseKey: ~
roleSessionAttribute: 'CKFinder_UserRole'
serveStaticResources: true
checkSizeAfterScaling: true
secureImageUploads: true
csrfProtection: false

backends:
  - name: 'default'
    adapter: 'local'
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8080/services/media/userfiles'
    root: '{user.dir}/userfiles'
    disallowUnsafeCharacters: true
    forceAscii: false
    hideFolders: ['.*', 'CVS', '__thumbs']
    hideFiles: ['.*']
    htmlExtensions: ['html', 'htm', 'xml', 'js']
    overwriteOnUpload: false
    useProxyCommand: false

resourceTypes:
  - name: 'Files'
    backend: 'default'
    directory: '/files'
    allowedExtensions: 7z,aiff,asf,avi,bmp,csv,doc,docx,fla,flv,gif,gz,gzip,jpeg,jpg,mid,mov,mp3,mp4,mpc,mpeg,mpg,ods,odt,pdf,png,ppt,pptx,pxd,qt,ram,rar,rm,rmi,rmvb,rtf,sdc,sitd,swf,sxc,sxw,tar,tgz,tif,tiff,txt,vsd,wav,wma,wmv,xls,xlsx,zip
    deniedExtensions: ~
    maxSize: 0
  - name: 'Images'
    backend: 'default'
    directory: '/images'
    allowedExtensions: bmp,jpeg,jpg,png
    deniedExtensions: ~
    maxSize: 1000000

privateDir:
  backend: 'default'
  path: '.ckfinder/'

thumbnails:
  enabled: true
  sizes:
    - width: 150
      height: 150
      quality: 80
    - width: 300
      height: 300
      quality: 80
    - width: 500
      height: 500
      quality: 80

images:
  maxWidth: 1600
  maxHeight: 1200
  quality: 80
  sizes:
    small:
      width: 480
      height: 320
      quality: 80
    medium:
      width: 600
      height: 480
      quality: 80
    large:
      width: 800
      height: 600
      quality: 80

cache:
  imagePreview: 86400  # 24 * 3600 (24h)
  thumbnails: 31536000 # 24 * 3600 * 365 (1 year)
  proxyCommand: 0

accessControl:
  - role: 'ROLE_MANAGER'
    resourceType: '*'
    folder: /

    FOLDER_VIEW: true
    FOLDER_CREATE: true
    FOLDER_RENAME: true
    FOLDER_DELETE: true

    FILE_VIEW: true
    FILE_CREATE: true
    FILE_RENAME: true
    FILE_DELETE: true

    IMAGE_RESIZE: true
    IMAGE_RESIZE_CUSTOM: true

  - role: 'ROLE_USER'
    resourceType: 'Images'
    folder: /

    FOLDER_VIEW: true
    FOLDER_CREATE: false
    FOLDER_RENAME: false
    FOLDER_DELETE: false

    FILE_VIEW: true
    FILE_CREATE: true
    FILE_RENAME: true
    FILE_DELETE: true

    IMAGE_RESIZE: false
    IMAGE_RESIZE_CUSTOM: false
```

If I understand, the ROLE_USER must only to have a acess to the 'Images' resource but ckfinder give access too at 'Files' resource (look screenshot below)

[Ckfinder folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhCoE.png)

Is it a mistake configuration or a bug to the ckfinder on JAVA ? I have tried with different role and resource type and always same result. I have the impression that the property 'resourceType' is not read.

Thanks for your answers.